# ActiveRecord & PHP: the best way to define different associations between two models

Tags: php, mysql, sql, activerecord, orm

I have models Page and Commit. Page has many Commits. 
But sometimes i need to get just one last commit for page, and sometimes to get history of page commits (20 last or all).

I wrote this code for models:

```
class Page extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $has_many = array(
        array('commits',
            'select'=> 'content',
            'order' => 'id DESC',
            'limit' => 1
        ));
}
class Commit extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('page'));
}
```

So what i need to do to have a chance for display all commits (['limit' => 20] for ex.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a workaround, but this should do it... kinda simulating scopes from Rails:

```
class Page extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $has_many = array(
        array('limited_commits',
            'class_name' => 'Commit',
            'select'=> 'content',
            'order' => 'id DESC',
            'limit' => 1
        ),
        array('all_commits',
            'class_name' => 'Commit',
            'select' => 'content',
            'order' => 'id DESC'
        )
    );
}
class Commit extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('page'));
}
```

And then just use the 'scope' you need:

```
Page::first->limited_commits
Page::first->all_commits
```

It's not a really overall solution, but it should do the trick...